# How does Kafka provides next batch of records to poll when commitAsync gets failed in committing offset

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I have a use-case regarding consuming records by Kafka consumer.
For instance,
I have 1 topic which has 1 partition. Currently, it has 10 records and while consuming the first 10 records, another 10 records are written to the partition.

1. myConsumer polls the first time and returns the first 10 records say 0 - 9 records.
2. It processed all the records successfully.
3. It invoked commitAsync() to Kafka to commit the last offset.
4. Commit response is in processing. It can be a success or a failure.
5. But, since it is an asynchronous mode, it continues to poll for the next batch.
6. Now, how does either Kafka or consumer poll know that it has to read from the 10th position? Because the commitAsync request has not yet completed.

Please help me in understanding this concept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Commit Offset tells the **broker** that the consumer has processed the corresponding message successfully. The consumer itself would be aware of its progress (except for start of consumer where it gets its last committed offset from broker).

At step-5 in your description, the commit offset is in progress. So:

- Broker does **not** know that 0-9 records have been processed
- Consumer itself has the read the messages and so it knows that is has read 0-9 messages. So it will know to read 10th onwards next.

#### Possible Scenarios

1. Lets say the commit fails for (0-9). Your next batch, say (10-15) is processed and committed succesfully then there is no harm done. Since we mark to the broker that processing till 15 is complete.
2. Lets say the commit fails for (0-9). Your next batch, (10-15) is processed and before committing, the consumer goes down. When your consumer is brought back up, it takes its state from broker (which does not have commit for either of the batch). So it will start reading from 0th message.

You can come up with several other scenarios as well. I guess the bottom line is, the importance of commit will come into picture when your consumer is restarted for whatever reason and it has get its last processed offset from kafka broker.

Comment: Thank you, @Rishabh Sharma. I understood it.